# Java Timezone Issue

Tags: java, timezone

Using **Timezone.getTimeZone**("Antarctica/Casey"), certain time zones are returning the invalid output. For eg.,

```
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa zzz" );  
outputFormat.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "Antarctica/Casey" ) );  
System.out.println(outputFormat.format( new Date() ));
```

Which suppose to return "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa **CAST**", but it returning "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa **WST**".

Like this here are the few other things having issues,

1. Australia/Adelaide - ACST / ACDT
2. Australia/Eucla - ACWST / ACWDT
3. Australia/Sydney - AEST / AEDT
4. Antarctica/Mawson - AHMT
5. Australia/Perth - AWST / AWDT
6. Pacific/Apia - SST.

Answer (score 5):

If you check [the IANA Time Zone Database](ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/data/antarctica), you will see that Casey is currently on the WST timezone and has been since February 2012.

```
# Zone  NAME        GMTOFF  RULES   FORMAT  [UNTIL]
Zone Antarctica/Casey   0   -   zzz 1969
            8:00    -   WST 2009 Oct 18 2:00
                        # Western (Aus) Standard Time
            11:00   -   CAST    2010 Mar 5 2:00
                        # Casey Time
            8:00    -   WST 2011 Oct 28 2:00
            11:00   -   CAST    2012 Feb 21 17:00u
            8:00    -   WST
```

Here is a more detailed reference to the change: http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/antarctica-2012.html.

However WST is only used when printing: internally the changes from GMT+8 to GMT+11 are correctly handled. See for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa Z");
  TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Antarctica/Casey");
  outputFormat.setTimeZone(tz);

  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

  //May 2014 = GMT + 8
  System.out.println(outputFormat.format(c.getTime()));

  //january 2012 = GMT + 11
  c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);
  c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
  System.out.println(outputFormat.format(c.getTime()));
}
```

As for the other differences, it is probably the difference between summer and winter time.

Comment: When you have almost 24 hours of dark or 24 hours of sun, I guess timezone is just a matter of practicality.

Comment: @assylias, Australia/Adelaide suppose to return **ACST / ACDT** but its returning **CST**,
Australia/Eucla suppose to return **ACWST / ACWDT** but its returning **CWST**,
Australia/Sydney suppose to return **AEST / AEDT** but its returning **EST**,
Antarctica/Mawson -  suppose to return **AHMT** but its returning **MAWT**,
Australia/Perth -  suppose to return **AWST / AWDT** but its returning **WST**,
Pacific/Apia -  suppose to return **SST** but its returning **WST**.

Whats the reason these zones are returning the invalid output?

Comment: I don't know I'm afraid. But the jdk uses the IANA database so you may find your answer in there.

Comment: @assylias I did a quick check. While some of these nationally-defined zone descriptions are in listed [tzdata](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), their localized definitions seem to be part of a locale. Java now uses by default the locale definition data provided by the Unicode Consortium’s [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org) such as this [page for North America](https://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/36/by_type/timezones.north_america.html) showing values for ‹Alaska Time›, ‹Alaska Standard Time›, ‹Alaska Daylight Time›, ‹Central Time›, ‹Central Standard Time›, ‹Central Daylight Time›, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your java version:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u-relnotes-515228.html

The timezone fix was done in tzdata2014f (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html):

Australian eastern time zone abbreviations are now AEST/AEDT not EST, and similarly for the other Australian zones.

So, to solve this issue, we need to update Java to at least **7u75**.